# Simple dropdown menu with CSS in a navba

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, dropdown

I'm trying to create a simple dropdown menu (with only CSS) in a navbar with multiple links, the problem is that the dropdown menu will show with every link and not only with the desired one. Here is the code:

HTML & CSS

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.topNav {
  background-color: #ff66b3;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
}

.topNav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.topNav a:hover {
  background-color: #ffb3d9;
  color: black;
}

.dropDown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  min-width: 160px;
}

.dropDown a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.topNav .mainLink:hover .dropDown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topNav" id="myTopnav">
  <a class="mainLink" id="menuIcon" href="#home">&#9776</a>
  <a class="mainLink" href="#home">NerdBook</a>
  <div class="dropDown">
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The dropdown will have to show only on the "menuIcon" link.

Comment: Change `.mainLink:hover` to `#menuIcon:hover` ... but actually your code when I put it into the snippet doesn't work , dropdown ins't a child of your links change it to `#menuIcon:hover  ~ .dropDown`

Comment: @DaniP already done, and not working.

Comment: @DaniP well, that kinda works but when you move pointer the menu will fade out and also it is lnline and not dropdown

Answer (score 1):

You already have an ID on the `<a>` tag you want to trigger the `:hover` so use that as reference selector. Also your code doesn't work because `.dropDown` ins't a child of your link change it to match as sibling:

> #menuIcon:hover ~ .dropDown

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.topNav {
  background-color: #ff66b3;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
}
.topNav:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
.topNav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.topNav a:hover {
  background-color: #ffb3d9;
  color: black;
}
.dropDown {
  background:#e1e1e1;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  z-index: 1;
  min-width: 160px;
}

.dropDown a {
  float:none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

#menuIcon:hover ~ .dropDown, .dropDown:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topNav" id="myTopnav">
  <a class="mainLink" id="menuIcon" href="#home">&#9776</a>
  <a class="mainLink" href="#home">NerdBook</a>
  <div class="dropDown">
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've answered you up there

Comment: Yep @Simone check the snippet edited now is working with minor changes on your CSS

Comment: ok it's more likely than what I want to have. But the links are still inline and not like a dropdown menu.

Comment: @Simone because you float all the a tags inside the div just change it to none float the onse inside dropdown, check the edited snippet .... I use a gray background just to show